# What happened to Bento Linux?

Tags: history, distributions

I came across a nifty device at a yard sale from ~2010, and at the time there was a distro called [Bento Linux](http://www.bento-linux.org/) that had [been ported to run on it](https://www.yourwarrantyisvoid.com/2011/07/25/cvs-netbook-revisited/comment-page-1/).  It seems that that distro died, but there are a variety of other things called Bento now, including possible projects that carried on the same idea ([Bento Openbox](https://linuxvillage.org/en/blog/tag/bento-linux/)).  Also, it's possible that the project has been carried on in another name, but I'm coming up empty looking for details.

There are a lot of references [to a site that has since died](http://devio.us/~nextvolume/via_arm/viewtopic.php?id=4&t_id=167).  Tangentally, I managed to find the [Android image](https://www.mediafire.com/file/1w95cruc3s0v6ew/Android_FLUX_NB_WMT216.7z/file) that is referenced the same time as the previous link, but I haven't found anything else on the Linux distro file or what happened to Bento Linux.

I'd like to know what happened to Bento Linux and if there is a derivative that is still alive, or if the ones I found are unrelated.

Comment: @roaima none of the above, as the question clearly indicates.

Comment: @roaima I mean... that would be true on the face of it.  I figured you were looking for a reason to vote to close it though.

Comment: @roaima I'd like to know what happened to Bento Linux and if there is a derivative that is still alive, or if the ones I found are unrelated.  Not sure how else to ask that....

Comment: The developer behind Bento linux is Mélodie. Maybe you can ask directly via [this link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/melodie).